# Get Length of Polygon in meters in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon

I have used Google Maps API to draw a polygon based on an array of lng/lat coordinates, but **I need a way to get the length of the polygon in meters**, is this possible using the Google Maps API?

I can't use the directionsService to draw a route and get the dinstance that way, because part of the path is off-road, and that changes the path when using the directionsService :(

This is how I create the polygon:

```
var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
                                paths: waypoints,
                                strokeColor: '#00FF00',
                                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                                strokeWeight: 2,
                                fillColor: '#00FF00',
                                fillOpacity: 0
                            });
poly.setMap(map);
```

Where waypoints is an array of objects like this:

```
[
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
          {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
          {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
          {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you can use the [Geometry Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) which you need to include in your API call in this way:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=geometry
```

To get the path(s) of your Polygon, use your `waypoints` array or get it from the Polygon object:

```
var path = poly.getPath(); // To retrieve the first path or
var paths = poly.getPaths(); // To retrieve all the paths
```

Then pass it to the Geometry `computeLength` function:

```
var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(path);
```

The function will get you the path length in meters.

Make sure you get the appropriate path(s) if your Polygon has multiple paths.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!